# Laravel use newly created entry directly after insertion

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to print a newly created element added to database immediately after inserting.

For the insertion, this is hadled with

```
class CarrierController extends Controller
...
    public function create()
    {
...
        return view('admin.carriers.create', compact('components', 'suppliers', 'containers'));
```

for printing, I created a route and a view.

This Route is handling the print request:

```
Route::get('carriers/print-label/{carrier}', 'CarrierController@printLabel')->name('carriers.print-label');
```

Question is: How can I trigger the route for printing with the ID generated for the new element?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from create function redirect the user to print route

use the following code in your create method to redirect user to your print route

```
return redirect()->route('carriers.print-label',['carrier'=>'Your carrier value'])->with(compact('components', 'suppliers', 'containers'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got it to work, however, a small deviation from your answer, in store function in CarrierController:

```
$carrier = Carrier::create($request->all());
return view('admin.carriers.print-label', compact('carrier'));
```

Thanks.